# Java string constant pool

Tags: java, string

In Java,

```
String s1 =  new String("abc");
String s2 = new String("ab") + new String("cd");
```

Will string "abc" and "abcd" be created in string constant pool?

Answer (score 1):

Neither `s1` nor `s2` will point to strings in the constant pool because you created them by a combination of explicit constructor calls and concatenation. Only the string literals "abc", "ab", and "cd" will be in the constant pool.

You would need to explicitly `intern()` the new instances. In that case, `s1 == "abc"` would become true.

Comment: s2.intern(); String s3 = "abcd";       Why s2 == s3   is true in jdk1.7?

Comment: It should be true in any JDK since s2 an s3 should see the same instance in the constant pool.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I understand it finally.